# How to compare multiple dictionaries to find out duplicate keys and how many times they are repeated

Tags: python

I need to compare more than 2 dictionaries to find out how many duplicate keys and how many times they are repeated.
for example

```
D1 = {'a' : 'value', 'b': 'value', 'c': 'value', 'd', 'value'}
D2 = {'d', 'value', 'a' : 'value'}
D3 = {'a' : 'value', 'd', 'value', 'b': 'value'}
D4 = {'a' : 'value'}
```

the output shoule print repeated keys and how many times each key is repeated for example:

```
4-a # key 'a' is repeated 4 times accross dictionaries
2-b 
3-d
```

Comment: Was there a particular problem when you tried to do this?

Comment: this feels like a homework problem but idk could be wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List Comprehension and then just iterate through array

```
dic = [x for x in D1] + [x for x in D2] + [x for x in D3] + [x for x in D4]
ans = {} 
for x in dic:
    if x in list:
        ans[x] += 1
    else:
        ans[x] = 1
```

**update**
I forgot about dictionary comprehension, so you can shorten that up.

```
dic = [x for x in D1]+ [x for x in D2] +  [x for x in D3] + [x for x in D4]  
ans = {i:dic.count(i) for i in dic}
```

Comment: Since `list` is already used as a type, you should avoid using it as a variable name.

Answer (score 0):

```
someDict = {
    'D1' : {'a' : 'value', 'b': 'value', 'c': 'value', 'd': 'value'},
    'D2' : {'d': 'value', 'a': 'value'},
    'D3' : {'a' : 'value', 'd': 'value', 'b': 'value'},
    'D4' : {'a' : 'value'}
}

keyList = []

for key, value in someDict.items():
    for k, v in value.items():
        keyList.append(k)

res = {i:keyList.count(i) for i in keyList}
print(res)
```

Here i simply created a dict which stores all the other dicts. Then i iterated over the dicts, got all the keys and stored them into a list. Then using dict comprehension, i got the number of times the keys are repeated.